# Count records for every month, including those with zero results

Tags: mysql, count

How do I count the number of results from MySql database for every month in the past year wherein there might not exist a record for a specific month but it would show zero as the count? For instance, I would like to count the number of registrations that occurred every month, and include those results too where no registrations occurred.

```
    Month    Count
      1        4
      2        2
      .        .
      .        .
      6        0
      .        .
      .        .
```

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While although a lot of answers exist, I found most of them difficult to read and understand. However, using derived tables, I think it's easier to do so with the given query below, where we are trying to count the number of registrations for the past 12 months from user table:

```
select derived.mm as month, count(u.reg_date) as count from (
    SELECT 1 mm UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7  
    UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 
    UNION ALL SELECT 12
) derived
left join user u
on derived.mm = month(reg_date) 
    and u.reg_date > LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
group by derived.mm
```

**HOW THIS WORKS**

It derives a table (alias derived) which returns 12 rows, 1 for each of the 12 months, i.e. 1 to 12 [in the subquery; line 2].

It joins the month number of the registration date to the corresponding month number from the given derived table. [for months where no registrations occured, the joined reg_date result is null]

And clause is as usual, counting the previous 12 months [current month will be indexed at 12]

It groups the results by the original month index.

Hope this comes to help someone out.

Comment: I think it's better to handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: It really depends on the context. Of course application can handle this logic. However, if you ignore the first column from this set of result and only take the 2nd column, setting up application logic will be difficult.

Comment: The application logic is a breeze.

Comment: In my viewpoint, if you require it in a list, and you're using a row mapper, you'll need to write additional lines that can completely be avoided. If you know better methods, then please do suggest explicitly.